# Highlight table row based on condition in VBCS Oracle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the table row color based on "hot_flag" condition. If "hot_flag" is marked as "Y", mark the whole row of yellow color. I could only find one solution with row-template and the use of  and  tags. But I have 73 columns in my table. Repeating the  tag 73 times in order to highlight every cell of table is a very cumbersome task to do. Is there any other way I can achieve this functionality?

Below is my oj-table tag -

I have multiple templates as well on few of these columns.

Some help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I couldn't find a tag for VBCS